# onselect for h:selectManyListbox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[ 
  function editSelected(selBox)
  {
    var htmlstring = selBox.options[selBox.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(htmlstring);
  }
  //]]>
</script>
...
<h:selectManyListbox
  id="titles"
  value="#{detailModel.selectedTitles}"
  size="5"
  disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode}"
  onselect="editSelected(document.getElementById('detailForm:titles'))">

  <f:selectItems
    value="#{detailModel.getCollectionAsSortableMetadataStringList(detailModel.afterObject.metadata.getTitles())}"
    var="title"
    itemLabel="#{title.value}"
    itemValue="#{title.position}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

With the `onselect`, when I click on an option of the select, there is no reaction.
With `onclick` I have the expected behavior (a fenster with the selected text).

Do I miss something or do I something wrong?

Comment: don't you want to use `onchange` ? `onselect` = selecting text with mouse... isn't it ? try...

Comment: I saw that there is (or maybe not :) ) the possibility to use onselect and I thought that it would be sematically more correct... It is exactly what I want: select the text with the mouse and it's exactly what happens when I click on an entry in the SelectmanyListBox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely an oversight in the JSF spec. The `select` event is **not** supported on `<select>` elements. See also [HTML DOM level 2 specification chapter 1.6.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents)

> #### select
>
> The select event occurs when a user selects some text in a text field. This event is valid for INPUT and TEXTAREA elements.

Note that it doesn't mention the SELECT element. I've reported it as [spec issue 1113](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1113).

Comment: Thank you BalusC. Then what would be better to use? onclick, onchange, ...?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `onselect` works only on `h:inputText` or `h:inputTextarea` where you can select part of the text e.g. for copy/paste.

For `h:selectManyListbox` the `onclick` event is the right one to choose.

Comment: Here (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyListbox.html) is in the attribute list...

Comment: Yes I've read the docs. But from my experience the javadoc sometimes does not reflect the implementation correctly. Maybe this is the case for `onselect`.